# Git Organization

Tags: git, organization

New to git here and I have an organizational problem.

I have a file called MASTER and a file called OBJECTIVE. Depending on a specific parameter in MASTER, OBJECTIVE will either implement one algorithm, or another.  I would like to keep output from both versions active in my git repo, but I don't want to rename files based on the algorithm used.

Is there a best-practice for something like this in git?

Comment: Im not too sure if this is considered "best-practice", but using separate [branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)?

Comment: You want two different log files to have the same name....? Why?

Comment: It seams to me that your issue is not how to do something, is that you don't know Git itself. I would highly recommend going over this simple explanation of Git http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/. After that you should check this https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/.

This should give you a better understanding how Git itself works.

With this basic knowledge you can jump in to a more detailed explanation from hear https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need

```
\MASTER
\OBJECTIVE.algorithm1
\OBJECTIVE.algorithm2
```

and then some process that copies one of the latter two files to

```
\OBJECTIVE
```

In most scenarios like these, `OBJECTIVE` would not be committed to the repository since it's a generated file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think git is the right approach here. The most you can do is have a second branch for the second implementation, but that will mess up your git history for the implementation done on the off-branch.

Rather I suggest to do exactly what you said. Let the program take in a runtime argument either passed in as a flag similar to [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod), or some [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Depending on the frequency that you change between the two implementations, i would choose the flag approach for frequent switching, where for something like production vs development i would use the environment variables.